# Control-D ends getchar but not program, prog continues with garbage value in receiving variable?

Tags: c, getchar

I'm taking a user-inputted single character.  The program continues getting characters with getchar until it encounters a non-space character, then uses that character to print a display.

If the user enters control-D instead of a character, the getchar input terminates and the program should too.

```
   char border;
   printf("Enter the character for the border: ");
   while ((border = getchar()) != EOF && border != '\n') {
     if (!isspace(border)){
        break;
     }
   }
```

Except if I enter control-D, the loop terminates...and the program allots the garbage character ▒▒ to border, then continues the program.

I've tried `if (!border) { return 1; }` and attempting to return 1 if border compared to ▒▒ is true, but no dice either way.

What's going on, and how can I handle this?

Comment: To be able to hold EOF border must be an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressing CTRL+D doesn't terminate the program. Instead, it closes the stdin input stream. Most command-line utilities are designed to do something and then terminate after this happens. Contrast this with CTRL+C, which sends a kill signal to the program.

Your code currently works by assigning the return value of `getchar()` to `border`, so if getchar returns EOF, it will assign EOF to border, then exit the loop. You can test for whether this happened by checking if border is equal to `EOF` after the loop.

As @Olaf pointed out, there's another issue here. Notice that `border` is a `char` and that `getchar` returns an integer. Change the type of `border` to `int` to prevent issues later on in your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you for the thorough explanation! As for actual implementation, comparing border to \n didn't work, but comparing it to EOF itself does -- since that's essentially what the stream assigned to it, I suppose.  Thank you again for helping me understand and fix the problem.

Comment: You did notice `border` is `char`, thus cannot represent EOF?

Comment: @Olaf Many systems use a signed `char` and `EOF` with a value of -1, so `char` _can_ hold the value of `EOF`.  The problem is not that `border` cannot represent the value of `EOF`, it is that a `char` can not distinguish between `EOF` and some `char` like `(char) 255`.

Comment: Perhaps I should not try to make people think themselves, but just provide a full solution instead :-). Never mind! AFAIS, the code from OP is ok except from the type issue.

Comment: @chux: Nope. a) whether `char` is signed or `unsigned` is _implementation defined_, and b) EOF is guaranteed not to equal a regular char. So, if an input character requires 8 bits (e.g. UTF-8) and `char` is signed, it is (most likely) returned as if `char` is unsigned: value in lower 8 bits and the rest of the `int` cleared.

Comment: @Olaf "whether char is signed or unsigned is implementation defined," is true but does not  negate my comment as that was addressing the case when `char ` is signed.  .  "EOF is guaranteed not to equal a regular char." is not true.  `EOF` is negative and `getchar()` returns an `unsigned char` or `EOF`.  So in a signed `char` system, `getc()` may return 255 which when saved in a `char`,  gets an implementation value such as `-1` - which may equal `EOF`.

Comment: @chux: You make a lot of assumptions here. For `signed char` you are basically right, but that is just an assumption. many compilers even allow to configure the signed'ness of `char` by option or pragma and `char` being signed for most ssystemshas yet to be proved. I know quite some systems where this is not true. Most prominent would be ARM - see AAPCS-7.1.1. For `char` being unsigned, this is promoted to `int`, too, but yields `(int)255`, which never equals `EOF`, as that is [always negative](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p2): program never terminates.

Comment: Agree on a typical system where `char` is unsigned, a `char ` will not have a value of `EOF`. My comments qualified that right away as I was addressing systems where `char` is signed.  Yes `getc()` returns type `int`, but in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  "7.21.7.1 The fgetc function".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81344/discussion-between-chux-and-olaf).

Answer (score 3):

There is a chain of problems actually:

- `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`.
- Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is not fixed by the standard, but implementation dependend.
- `EOF` is *always* a [negative](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p2) `int`.
- A valid `char` returned by `getchar()` is returned non-negative (simplified: the character code is in the lower bits, the uppermost bits are 0). So it is actually `unsigned char` converted to `int`.
- For comparisons, type promotion is applied first to a common type. As `char` has a lower rank than `int`, it is promoted to `int` (zero- or sign-extended).

In any case, the cast maps `EOF` to a valid character code from the extended character set (the base set is actually ASCII and in the range 0..127). This *shadows* the character, making both indistinguishable in the first place.

However, due to type promition, comparing with `EOF` yields different results for `signed char` and `unsigned char`:

- `signed char`, `CHAR_MIN <= EOF` (always < 0): The compare will work, but the original char will be errorneously treated as `EOF`, too.
- `signed char`, `EOF < CHAR_MIN` (e.g. -129): That is actually *undefined behaviour*, everything can happen. For the typical case (2s complemente, upper bits truncated, the result can very well be positive. Never compares equal to the (negative!) `EOF`.
- `unsigned char`: promoted to positve integer, never equals the (negative) `EOF`.

Note also not to make any assumptions about `EOF except for what the standard defines (it is negative). So, always asign`getchar()`to an`int`, test for`EOF`and **then** convert to`char`.

Try this to see the values returned by `getchar()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
       int ch;
       do {
              ch = getchar();
              printf("0x%08X\n", ch);
       } while ( ch != EOF ) ;
}
```

Remember: input is line-buffered, so you have to press return to see the values.